# How to return view in .NET Core when configuration set to app.UseAPIResponseWrapper() in startup.cs file

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

View is returning 500 status code when `app.UseApiResponseWrapper()` is added in `startup.cs` file.

I want to return View when controller action method hits for particular one action method and for remaining action methods `app.UseApiResponseWrapper()` should apply.

How can I omit `app.UseApiResponseWrapper()` for particular action method.

Comment: What is `UseAPIResponseWrapper`?

Comment: @Alex Riabov - https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/asp-net-core-and-web-api-a-custom-wrapper-for-managing-exceptions-and-consiste/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Conditional middleware with UseWhen logic, wrap your 
app.UseApiResponseWrapper() with condition, e.g.:

```
app.UseWhen(context => !context.Request.Path.ToString().Contains("ActionToOmit"), appBuilder =>
{
    appBuilder.UseApiResponseWrapper();
});
```

Comment: Thanks for quick response but not working. I added in startup.cs file as below:
app.UseWhen(context => !context.Request.Path.ToString().Contains("Index"), appBuilder =>
            {
                app.UseApiResponseWrapper();
            })

My action method:
[Route("Index")]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

Comment: It needs to be appBuilder.UseApiResponseWrapper() rather than app.UseApiResponseWrapper(). Have edited the answer.